# MySQL Insert to with Multiple Checks

Tags: php, mysql

In a facebook app he have the following DB columns:

```
id (auto_increment)
facebook_id (VARCHAR)
email (VARCHAR)
like_name (VARCHAR)
like_id (VARCHAR)
```

If we want to allow multiple entries for the same facebook_id, but not allow duplicates of the like_id for each facebook_id, what would be the query?  We want to allow multiple facebook_id's to have the same like_id.  Do we need to set any indexes?  We tried doing a DUPLICATE KEY Update, but it does not work.

```
    $likessql = $conn->prepare('INSERT IGNORE likes (facebook_id,email,like_name,like_id) VALUES(:facebook_id,:email,:like_name,:like_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE like_id = :like_id');
    foreach ($likes as $like) {
        $likessql->execute(array(
        ':facebook_id' => $facebookid,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':like_name' => $like['name'],
        ':like_id' => $like['id']
    ));
```

Comment: Please show how indices (constraints) do look like currently

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please answer it and mark it as correct.

Comment: @DavidEisen Great. Other than having a unique constraint (PK in your case), that you already figured out, here is another thing: you either **IGNORE** or **UPDATE** when duplicate has been found. Not both. So I'd suggest to ditch the whole `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, by setting two primary indexes as PRIMARY Seq_in_index = 1 , Column_name = facebook_id .  The second index is PRIMARY Seq_in_index = 2, Column_name = like_id .  Basically I had to set the primary key to two items.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `UNIQUE` constraint with multiple columns in it. This will prevent using multiple PRIMARY KEYs, and is, in my opinion, the proper way to do this.

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) for more details.

Good Luck!